# How to enforce commit message for github PR commits only?

Tags: github

I know there are multiple node packages out there to enforce commit message format but they all seem to be done pre-commit, locally for 'all' checkins.  Is there a way to enforce a commit message format only for the merging of PR to master, and not all checkins?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a native github method to achieve this, then no. There's no way to make github itself check your commit message for some pattern.

Otherwise, what you want is a status check to fail if commits messages do not meet your standard with github configured to disallow PR merge while any check fails. The simples way I can think of is to enable Travis-ci integration for the project and use one of the npm modules you mentioned as the test code and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

There's now a github app that allows this: https://github.com/zeke/semantic-pull-requests. If you want to ensure that all your PR titles are semantically correct (perhaps because you're squash merging) be sure to add the configuration file and specify `titleOnly: true`